# How do I organize the output of this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The output of this program is a table, but it is kind of messy. How to **align** the different columns? Thanks

**Code:**

```
import math   

for a in range(1, 10):
    x = 3.0
    while True:
        y = (x + a/x) / 2
        if y == x:
            break
        x = y  
    sq = math.sqrt(a)
print float(a), sq, x, abs(sq - x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
import math   

for a in range(1, 10):
    x = 3.0
    while True:
        y = (x + a/x) / 2
        if y == x:
            break
        x = y  
    sq = math.sqrt(a)
    print '{:>5} {:>5.10f} {:>5.10f} {:>5.10f}'.format(float(a), sq, x, abs(sq - x))
```

prints

```
  1.0 1.0000000000 1.0000000000 0.0000000000
  2.0 1.4142135624 1.4142135624 0.0000000000
  3.0 1.7320508076 1.7320508076 0.0000000000
  4.0 2.0000000000 2.0000000000 0.0000000000
  5.0 2.2360679775 2.2360679775 0.0000000000
  6.0 2.4494897428 2.4494897428 0.0000000000
  7.0 2.6457513111 2.6457513111 0.0000000000
  8.0 2.8284271247 2.8284271247 0.0000000000
  9.0 3.0000000000 3.0000000000 0.0000000000
```